# R: How to reshape a table into vectors

Tags: r, list, vector, reshape

I'm working through the examples in Kruschke's `Doing Bayesian Data Analysis` and need a bit of help understanding how to get data into the format that his code examples require. In chapter 22 he has a table like this

```
         Blue  Brown  Green Hazel
Black    20    68     5     15
Blond    94    7      16    10
Brunette 84    119    29    54
Red      17    26     14    14
```

I'm comfortable with inputting the table into `R` by entering it into a spreadsheet and using `read.table("clipboard", header=T, sep="\t")` or typing it into `R` like this

```
con.table2 <- matrix(c(20,68,5,15,94,7,16,10,84,119,29,54,17,26,14,14),nrow=4,byrow=TRUE)
dimnames(con.table2) <- list(c("Black","Blond","Brunette","Red"),c("Blue","Brown","Green","Hazel"))
```

But in his code, he presents this table like so, ready for analysis (full code is here http://www.indiana.edu/~kruschke/DoingBayesianDataAnalysis/Programs/PoissonExponentialJagsSTZ.R)

```
Freq = c(68,119,26,7,20,84,17,94,15,54,14,10,5,29,14,16)
Eye = c("Brown","Brown","Brown","Brown","Blue","Blue","Blue","Blue","Hazel" # runs off the page of his book
Hair = c("Black","Brunette","Red","Blond","Black","Brunette","Red","Blond","Black" # runs off the page of his book
```

It looks like the table has been converted into three vectors. What's the most efficient way to do this? I'd like to replace his data with my own, so it would be great to learn how to transform the data into the format needed for this analysis.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For this, I'd use `melt()` in the `reshape2` package:

```
library(reshape2)
df <- melt(con.table2, varnames=c("Hair", "Eye"), value.name="Freq")

# df is a data frame, a list from which you can easily extract the
# component vectors "Hair", "Eye", and "Freq. 
# Try, for example:
str(df)
df$Hair
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a method in base R for converting objects of class "table" to data.frames. The reason that it does not succeed with your matrix is that you didn't tell R that it was a table. Once you do so the method succeeds:

```
class(con.table2) <- "table"
as.data.frame(con.table2)
#-----------------------
       Var1  Var2 Freq
1     Black  Blue   20
2     Blond  Blue   94
3  Brunette  Blue   84
4       Red  Blue   17
5     Black Brown   68
6     Blond Brown    7
7  Brunette Brown  119
8       Red Brown   26
9     Black Green    5
10    Blond Green   16
11 Brunette Green   29
12      Red Green   14
13    Black Hazel   15
14    Blond Hazel   10
15 Brunette Hazel   54
16      Red Hazel   14
```

The "table" class in R is expected to be a contingency table (just as you have constructed), i.e, one with counts in cells. In this case you could have had fractional values in there and there would be no problems but some methods that were expecting the values to be integer might choke on non-integer values.

Comment: I was thinking along these lines using `df <- as.data.frame(as.table(con.table2)); names(df) <- c("hair", "eye", "freq")`

Answer (score 2):

Since your data is in a matrix, with the hair colour as row names, you can first convert it to a data.frame, and then use `melt` to convert it to a tall format.

```
d <- data.frame(
  Hair = rownames(ch_22_table),
  as.data.frame( ch_22_table )
)
library(reshape2)
melt(d, id.vars="Hair", variable.name="Eye", value.name="Freq")
```

Comment: Turns out `melt()` has a method for matrices (`melt.array()`), so there's no need to first convert to the matrix to a data.frame. Nice, ennit?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien: I was not aware of it. My first movement is always to normalize the data (i.e., to put it in a tall format), and only then do I start to think...

Comment: Clearly `melt()` is the way to go and I need to get more familiar with it. Thanks for your suggestion.